# Regex para formato de número

Tags: php, regex

Como posso criar uma regex (que será usada com `preg_match`) para o seguinte formato **`1.123,12`**?

Comment: Quais as variações do número? Ele tem limite máximo ou mínimo, de 0 até milhão,bilhão...?

Comment: É de 0 até um milhão

Comment: Esse número vem da onde?

Comment: vem de um ficheiro csv e ao importar para um base dados fica só 1.12 se conseguir verificar quais são os casos em que isso acontece posso fazer o NumberFormatter do numero .

Comment: O melhor é usar o `NumberFormatter` nem precisa de regex, lembre que o ponto é o separador de decimal por isso seu número fica errado, o certo seria ficar: `1123.12`, vc pode tentar inicialmente trocar o ponto por nada e a vírgular por ponto.

Comment: sim mais eu não queria esta estar a fazer isso a cada registo porque também pode vir strings

Comment: Não acho que regex seja indicado para validação numérica. O ideal seria, como o @rray disse, usar uma classe ou função especial para isso. Faça isso seletivamente para os campos que você sabe que são numéricos. Isso deve estar indicado em algum lugar do código, não é mesmo? Se houver algum problema no valor, basta tratar a exceção ou valor de retorno adequadamente.

Answer (score 1):

*Pattern* para obter números de 0 até 9.999.999,99: "`((?:\d\.)?(?:\d{1,3}\.)?\d{1,3},\d{1,2})|(\d)`"

O *pattern* acima obtém números nos seguintes formatos:

- 0
- 0,00
- 00,00
- 0.000,00
- 000.000,00
- 0.000.000,00

Exemplo no [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/eI2fF9/2).

Eu acredito que devem ter maneiras melhores de resolver isso sem `regex`, mas eu conheço pouco de `php`.